# Why am I getting a rate limit error when ensuring that I do not surpass my rate limit?

Tags: python, python-3.x, openai-api

I am a new user of OpenAI API. I have written a Python script that places text into a .txt file and then feeds this text file along with a prompt into an OpenAI thread. From all I can tell, this process is working as I expect when I run it for a single file. I am encountering issues when trying to scale up and repeat this process, however. I try to iterate through the creation and analysis of 10 of my text files and am getting the following error:

```
LastError(code='rate_limit_exceeded', message='Rate limit reached for gpt-3.5-turbo-1106 in 
organization org-zCh0v22Q1oaob4QcpuOHgeu0 on requests per min (RPM): Limit 3, Used 3, Requested 1. 
Please try again in 20s. Visit https://platform.openai.com/account/rate-limits to learn more. You 
can increase your rate limit by adding a payment method to your account at 
https://platform.openai.com/account/billing.')
```

I understand that with my account level and the model I am using (gpt-3.5-turbo-1106), my limit is 3 requests per minute. However, I have tried placing a 20-second sleep function in my script in between requests to ensure that there could not possibly be more than 3 requests per minute. Adding to my confusion is the fact that, when I try to run the same 10 text files over and over, sometimes the process fails on the first file, sometimes on the third file, etc. I am unable to discern a pattern of when the program fails and when it succeeds, but it has never been able to make it through more than 5 files before failing.

Some more info: I am the only user using my API key and the only user in my organization. From what I can tell, then, either I do not understand what is being counted as a request, or the API is counting more requests than I am actually making. As I said, I am a new user and any help and advice is much appreciated! Including my code below:

```
import pandas as pd
import time
from openai import OpenAI

client = OpenAI(api_key = "[MY API KEY]")
thread = client.beta.threads.create()
assistant = client.beta.assistants.create(
    name = "Nomination Hearing Identifier",
    instructions = "Given a complete transcript of a US Senate hearing, determine if this hearing was or was not a nomination hearing. Respond with only 'YES' or 'NO' and do not provide justification.",
    tools = [{"type": "retrieval"}],
    model = "gpt-3.5-turbo-1106"
)

files = ["CHRG-108shrg1910401.txt","CHRG-108shrg1910403.txt", "CHRG-108shrg1910406.txt", "CHRG-108shrg1910407.txt", "CHRG-108shrg1910408.txt", "CHRG-108shrg1910409.txt", "CHRG-108shrg1910410.txt", "CHRG-108shrg1910411.txt", "CHRG-108shrg1910413.txt", "CHRG-108shrg1910414.txt"]

jacket_classifications = pd.DataFrame(columns = ["jacket", "is_nomination"])

for file in files:
    gpt_file = client.files.create(
        file = open(file, "rb"),
        purpose = 'assistants'
    )

    message = client.beta.threads.messages.create(
        thread_id=thread.id,
        role="user",
        content="Determine if the transcript in this file does or does not describe a nomination hearing. Respond with only 'YES' or 'NO' and do not provide justification.",
        file_ids=[gpt_file.id]
    )

    run = client.beta.threads.runs.create(
        thread_id=thread.id,
        assistant_id=assistant.id,
    )

    while run.status != "completed":
        run = client.beta.threads.runs.retrieve(
        thread_id=thread.id,
        run_id=run.id
        )
        print(run.status)
        if run.status == "failed":
            print(run.last_error)
            exit()

    messages = client.beta.threads.messages.list(
        thread_id=thread.id
    )

    output = messages.data[0].content[0].text.value
    if "yes" in output or "Yes" in output or "YES" in output:
        is_nomination = 1

    row = pd.DataFrame({"jacket":[file], "is_nomination":[is_nomination]})
    jacket_classifications = pd.concat([jacket_classifications, row])

    print("Sleeping 20 seconds to ensure API call rate limit not surpassed")
    time.sleep(20)

jacket_classifications.to_csv("[MY FILE PATH]/test.csv")
```

Comment: Does `client.beta.threads.runs.retrieve` send a request?

Comment: @TimRoberts I do believe that this was the problem. I was under the impression that just the creation of the run sent a request, but apparently the retrievals of the run do, as well, as placing the sleep inside of my while loop before each retrieval seems to have resolved my problem. Thank you!

Comment: Why not answer your own question?

Answer (score 1):

@Tim Roberts comment is correct. I now see that both the creation of a run *and* subsequent retrievals of that run both count toward the request rate count. So the run retrievals I was doing in the while loop were the problem; if I put a 40-second sleep inside of the while loop, the program works as desired and I can loop as many times as I want. Maybe I missed something or maybe it's common knowledge with API like this, but I feel like the definition of a request is somewhat poorly documented in OpenAI's documentation... hopefully this example can be of some use to someone else!